# Как получить доступ к классу настроек приложения из библиотеки dll?

Tags: c#

Имеется приложение и подключенная к нему библиотека. Необходимо из библиотеки изменить некоторые настройки (user settings)

Comment: Если приложение хочет этого, пусть передаёт объект с настройками в библиотеку. Если приложение не хочет этого, то этого делать не нужно.

Comment: В этом и вопрос. Как я понимаю сам объект `Settings` передать не получится

Comment: Непонятно. Вопрос в том, приложение _хочет_, чтобы его настройки меняли, или не хочет? Если хочет, пусть передаёт. Если не хочет, то менять не нужно.

Comment: Да, приложение хочет чтобы его настройки менялись из библиотеки. Как передать настройки в библиотеку чтобы там же их изменить и вызвав метод Save() они сохранились?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, проблема в том, что стандартный тип `Settings`, генерируемый для .NET-приложений — специфический класс, лежащий внутри самого класса приложения, и значит, библиотека не может на него ссылаться. Простое решение — передавать в библиотеку его базовый тип `System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase`.

Проблема лишь в том, что у вас не будет типизированного доступа к свойствам, так что вам придётся получать доступ по строковым именам. Вместо `int`-свойства `settings.Х` у вас будет `object`-индексатор `settings["X"]`.

Получится как-то так:

(Библиотека)

```
public void ProcessSettings(System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase settings)
{
    settings["X"] = 2;
    settings.Save();
}
```

(Приложение)

```
Library.ProcessSettings(Properties.Settings.Default);
```

Comment: А публичным сделать его нельзя?

Comment: @Андрей: Тогда будет проблема зависимостей. Библиотеке придётся добавлять приложение как reference. Но ведь и приложению надо добавлять библиотеку как reference! Замкнутый круг.